# Storing serialized object with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm

I got some problem with storing php serialized object with doctrine,
when I use the following code to store:

```
$item = new \Company\MyBundle\Entity\Frontend\table();
$item->setData(serialize($myPhpObject));
$this->_em->persist($item);
$this->_em->flush();
```

Then in another instance:

```
$item = $this->_em->getRepository('MyBundle:frontend\table')->findOneById(...);
echo $item->getData(); // display only a part of the serialized object
```

I found somehow a fix but I guess there is something better to do:

```
$item->setData(json_encode(serialize($myPhpObject)));
```

When I use this the all serialized string is stored and I can unserialize it correctly. Do you have any idea about what is wrong?

-edit-

this would be an example of setting from the column data:

```
data:
    type: string
    length: null
    fixed: false
    nullable: true
    column: data
```

Comment: Please give more details about object you are serializing, cuz there is many solutions depends on your object. And please, there is great manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php and in comments you can find many cases

Comment: Have you tried using Doctrine's built-in `object` field type?

Comment: Did you deserialize after getData()?

Comment: @pomaxa the object is Swift_Mime_Message from the swift mail library.

Comment: @kix I must give a look.

Comment: @Javad yes I need to unserialize afterward.

Comment: @Alexandre - please proviede MyBundle:frontend\table data field definition.

Comment: @Alexandre please post `data` field definition (annotation or yml). What doctrine type do you use?

Comment: @WebHQ I put the yml data field in my comment, see after the edit. The type is a string

Comment: @Alexandre First of all string is maximum 255 chars length. That's why you get  display only a part of the serialized object.
You have to change type to [object type](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types). See my answer for full feedback.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are using annotations as your doctrine configuration. Then in your entity you can use the `object` type:

```
// src/Company/MyBundle/Entity/Frontend/table.php
// ...
/**
 * @var resource
 *
 * (non-PHPdoc)
 * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="object")
 */
private $data;
// ...
```

Then inside your controller it is not necessary to serialize / unserialize object, doctrine will handle that:

```
// src/Company/MyBundle/Controller/SomeController.php
// ...
// write
$item = new \Company\MyBundle\Entity\Frontend\table();
$item->setData($myPhpObject);

$this->_em->persist($item);
$this->_em->flush();

// ...
// read
$item = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CompanyMyBundle:table')->find($id);
$myPhpObject = $item->getData();
var_dump($myPhpObject);
// ...
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using `ArrayType` (a.k.a. `array` in Entity Annotation) or `ObjectType` (a.k.a. `object` in Entity Annotation) for Doctrine type might have some potential security issues (causing a Denial of service) because of this issue (https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3289)

I, myself, would use JsonObjectType instead.

Comment: I moved the issue to the Doctrine DBAL project where it belongs :)

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3289